# GKTurnBasedMatch: Trouble Getting/Setting the matchOutcome

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, game-center

I am working on a Game Center based board game.  All seems to be running grew with a few bugs and quirks here and there.  The most annoying of those quirks is that when viewing a match that has ended, it always seems to think that the viewing player has lost.

When I end a match with a game winning move, I run this:

```
// Act if the game is over because of that move
if ([board playerHasWon:activePlayer]) {
    board.canMove = NO;
    match = [CNFTurnBasedMatchHelper sharedInstance].currentMatch;
    NSUInteger currentIndex = [match.participants indexOfObject:match.currentParticipant];
    NSUInteger nextIndex = (currentIndex == 0 ? 1 : 0);
    GKTurnBasedParticipant *nextParticipant = [match.participants objectAtIndex:nextIndex];
    match.currentParticipant.matchOutcome = GKTurnBasedMatchOutcomeWon;
    nextParticipant.matchOutcome = GKTurnBasedMatchOutcomeLost;
    [match endMatchInTurnWithMatchData:[[board stringValue] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] completionHandler:nil];
}
```

However, I suspect the real problem lies in my retrieval of that matchOutcome.

When loading a match I run this if the it's not the current players turn:

```
if (match.status == GKTurnBasedMatchStatusEnded) {
    // These lines get the board to show the winning line
    [board playerHasWon:1];
    [board playerHasWon:2];
    board.canMove = NO;
    if (match.currentParticipant.matchOutcome == GKTurnBasedMatchOutcomeWon) statusLabel.text = @"You won!";
    else statusLabel.text = @"You lost!";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I solved my own problem just by really laying it out.

```
if ([((GKTurnBasedParticipant*)[match.participants objectAtIndex:0]).playerID isEqualToString:[GKLocalPlayer localPlayer].playerID]) {
    if ([board playerHasWon:1]) statusLabel.text = @"You won!";
    else statusLabel.text = @"You lost!";
}
else {
    if ([board playerHasWon:2]) statusLabel.text = @"You won!";
    else statusLabel.text = @"You lost!";
}
```